# Delphi: declare variable avoiding circular reference

Tags: delphi, circular-reference

I've got a Delphi unit which needs to keep the pointer of various forms of the application, to do operations on them later.

In order to do those operations, I need to cast the pointer to a form type, ex.

```
var    
  ptrFrmMain: Pointer;
  CurrentFrmMain: TfrmMain;
begin
    CurrentFrmMain := ptrFrmMain;
    CurrentFrmMain.Close();
end;
```

The problem is that this unit is contained in the uses of all the other Delphi units of the application. So while I can declare a simple `Pointer` type in the interface section, I cannot declare a type declared in the other units (such as `TfrmMain` of the unit `frmMain.pas`).

I could solve this by placing a use in the implementation section, such as:

```
interface
type TMyThread = class(TThread)
  Public
    ptrFrmMain:Pointer
...

implementation
    uses frmMain

    var
      CurrentFrmMain: TfrmMain;
```

but there is still a problem: I need the variable to be specific to my class instance, for multithread purposes, and not a generic global variable.
But I cannot place it inside my `TmyThread` class, since `TfrmMain` is not declared there and I cannot place it in the uses of the interface section.

A solution would be to place `CurrentFrmMain` as a local variable in all the procedures which use it and then do the `CurrentFrmMain := ptrFrmMain` conversion each time, but do you know a better solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can typecast your pointer in-place or you can declare as generic base TForm...

Comment: @FreeConsulting I cannot declare as generic base Tform because I need to call functions which are specific of my form, ex.
'CurrentFrmMain.MyFunction()'

Comment: @FreeConsulting Also, casting the pointer in-place it was a solution I mentioned, but I'd prefer not to have to reinitialize it in each function

Comment: Declare the variable as a TForm and then cast it to the specific form type using `as` in the implementation section. This does not "reinitialize" anything, it simply refers to the existing form(s) using a reference of the correct type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, using `as` wouldn't that be kind of the same of casting the `MyCurrentFrom` from `Pointer` `ptrMyCurrentForm` ? In both cases, it must be done locally inside a procedure, so I have to place it in each function which uses the form, without the possibility to place it globally and having to initialize it only once.

Comment: No, it would not. `As` checks if the form is really the type of form you specify and throws and exception if not. It is a type safe cast. You can check the type before with `is`. Also note that `as` and `is` only work on objects, not on untyped pointers.

Comment: The general pattern is: `if MyForm is TFormABCD then MyFormABCD := MyForm as TFormABCD; // now you can use MyFormABCD`.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't put a Form pointer in the thread at all. I would have the thread hold callback functions instead, or even an interface:

```
type
  TCloseProc: procedure of object;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    CloseProc: TCloseProc;
    ...
  end;

...

begin
  if Assigned(CloseProc) then CloseProc();
end;
```

```
type
  IMyIntf = interface(IInterface)
  ['{9CC7DB9E-D47F-4B7D-BBF9-6E9B80823086}']
    procedure DoClose;
  end;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    Intf: IMyIntf;
    ...
  end;

...

begin
  if Assigned(Intf) then Intf.DoClose();
end;

...

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm, IMyIntf)
  public
    procedure doClose;
  end;

procedure TfrmMain.doClose;
begin
  Close;
end;
```

When the thread is created, assign the Form methods to those callbacks, or pass the Form's interface implementation to the thread:

```
Thread := TMyThread.Create(True);
Thread.CloseProc := frmMain.Close;
Thread.Resume;
```

```
Thread := TMyThread.Create(True);
Thread.Intf := frmMain as IMyIntf;
Thread.Resume;
```

Either way, the thread doesn't need to know about the actual Forms at all while still catering to Form-specific functionality.

Comment: Interfaces are neat, but isn't their danger to be hit by ARC and unexpected freeing forms ?

Comment: Guess there to be a guard-check added if a given object of a form even implements the needed interface....

Comment: @Arioch'The: ARC is not a problem in VCL at least because `TComponent` disables reference counting of interfaces implemented by component objects, and `TForm` is a `TComponent` descendant.  And the `as` operator provides the necessary check for the interface implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Depends upon what do you mean by "keep the pointer of various forms of the application, to do operations on them later." - what kind (or kinds) of work that is? This is a question about generic software design, about decomposition, not just `circular reference` or any other language-specific issue.

If all you want to do is making same work over any form - then you should derive your forms from the same BASE-FORM-CLASS and keep references to that base class, not to the specific form classes. For example if you just need to `.Release` them you can just keep them all as `TForm` type reference which they all are derived from. This is just a typical case of extracting common abstract interface.

```
TMyFormWithActions = class ( TForm ) .... end;    
TMyForm1234 = class ( TMyFormWithActions ) .... end;
TMyFormABCD = class ( TMyFormWithActions ) .... end;
```

You can also extract the common functionality not into intermediate class, but into the MS COM `interface` like Remy shown in his answer. This however is bordering with quite different memory model (ARC one) MS COM was based upon. While I do not expect `TForm` have auto-destroy reference counting, I also am not totally sure it can't happen, especially in inherited and complex application. So while I do like that approach, I omitted it because sometimes in practice it might cause unexpected and premature death of objects. If you can ensure that would not happen though it might be the most clean solution.

---

And if you need to do DIFFERENT actions, then you can indeed not merely store references to forms themselves, but also to actions, to software snippets. Then your thread-declaring class would build a general framework to keep forms-and-procedures data cells. And then you would have extra units implementing those specific actions to be passed.

( thread-and-action interface unit )  == `uses` ==>   ( actions for TMyFormABCD unit )  <== `uses` == ( TMyFormABCD form declaration unit )

As a simplified option, you can declare those actions in the same units as forms themselves. Then you would have all form-units depend upon thread-unit, but thread-unit (remade to be generic and specific forms-agnostic) would no more depend upon any of forms-unit. Probably it might be called "Inversion of control".

See this series: http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/16/the-visitor-pattern-part-1/

---

And one more scheme to design this, which can be seen as implementing BOTH of those approaches - would be using Windows Messages.
Your "common interface", your "actions" would be represented by custom WM_xxx messages (integer consts) you would make. Then your thread would use `PostMessage` API to signal those actions to the forms. And those forms - by implementing methods to deal with those messages ( or by non-implementing = ignoring those messages ) would provide those action-implementations.

See: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/howto_send_custom_window_message.htm

`PostMessage` can be used from external thread but can not (easily) return values. `SendMessage` can only be used from the main Delphi thread. Also you have to check if `MyTargetForm.HandleAllocated()` before posting messages.

Comment: I cannot use the generic base Tform class because I need to call functions which are specific of my form, ex. 'CurrentFrmMain.MyFunction()'. 
So I'd like to be able to easily call these functions, without having to rewrite much of the code (and if possible keep CurrentFrmMain variable as a class member, and not have to use it as a local variable, which would need to be reinitialized from pointer in each function which uses it).

Comment: what do you mean by "specific of my form" - specific intention ( = declaration = interface = contract ), or specific implementation (aka "virtual functions" and "abstract functions" ) ?

Comment: if you want to have absolutely different actions over different forms - then read the Visitor Pattern sequence. You would have to step away and look at the larger picture of how to decompose your program. How to design blocks of it. Where to put actions, where to put forms, it. There are several possible schemes and they all have their trade-offs, and only you knowing your program work can try to guess which would be less problematic.

Comment: I mean that in my TfrmMain class I have added custom functions which are not present in the base TForm.
I use those functions as TfrmMain class members because they use a lot of component and properties of that form.
So to give an idea:

frmCalculator.Add()

frmCalculator.Subtract()

...

Comment: @Flavio: I am sure Arioch 'The got that. Take a closer look at his latest advice.

Comment: but why ever use those function in that mega-uber-unit of "the pointer of various forms of the application" ? Why do you need that unit in the first place? Application already knows all its forms! So why do you have to duplicate that functionality and make your own non-standard forms list? What that list even serves for ? why not just remove that list ?

Comment: @Flavio I feel that you have to make few steps back and look at the whole picture from fresh perspective. I feel like you run into the dead end, and are looking at the walls, rather than walking back to open place. It is what was coined as "what is you Z here" or "Describe the goal, not the step" as http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: @Arioch'The I think to make you better understand I must explain some more.
This unit manages socket connection and receives various commands from a remote client. When receiving a command, I must know to which form must be sent to be processed.
So this unit must retrieve the pointer of the form and cast it, in order to call my function which is a member of my form class.

Comment: Does this unit works in the single main VCL thread as all the forms do? If it lives in  some other thread then it can not use those forms and their methods directly anyway.

Comment: To solve this, I could simply put a var CurrentMyFrm: TMyFrm in each function which calls functions from CurrentMyFrm, and before using any member function of CurrentMyFrm, I load it from pointer like this: CurrentMyFrm := ptrMyFrm.  This is an easy solution, but I'd like to know if there's a simple way which does not force me to reinitialize from pointer each time.

Comment: Okay, the unit received the command like "xxx-yyy-222-444" - how does it know it should create/find form of `TMyFromABCD` class ? Is there a dialog, when the form gets REPLIES to its requests? Or if there a fixed pre-compiled "command pattern -> implementing class" list ?

Comment: This unit works in separate thread. I can call form procedure with no problem, even though sometimes I need to use the Synchronize() function to execute part of code in the Main VCL thread.

Comment: Personally I would prefer using `PostMessages` approach and pass the non-parsed (or very lightly parsed) message to the form (or to some proxy class between sockets and forms) like I told in "( thread-and-action interface unit ) == uses ==> ( actions for TMyFormABCD unit ) <== uses == ( TMyFormABCD form declaration unit )"

Comment: Basically, assume that the socket reply message contains the pointer of the associated local form. This pointer was sent to the remote client, before, when sending the first message from my local application, in order to know to which form send the reply when getting the reply socket message.

Comment: Basically in this situation you DO have the same BASE CLASS INTERFACE and that interface is `procedure/function HandleSocketMessage(const DATA: socket-message-data)`. All the form-specific knowledge and functions should be dealt with from within that unified function! And that function would be made either in the form itself or in special proxy(bridge) class, linking its target form class with socket manager

Comment: MAYBE you would have some insights from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model and https://github.com/frankshearar/ikaria

Comment: Thanks, this `HandleSocketMessage` idea, so unifying all calls to that form in a single function, is definitely a good idea and approach.

Comment: @Flavio: note that that HandleSocketMessage (or whatever you call it) should be part of a base class from which all forms derive. If HandleSocketMessage is virtual, you can override it in each specific form class to do what that form needs to do. ISTM that you also may want to separate your logic (your model) from the forms (your presentation). Do not put all code in event handlers. Only the code that is directly responsible for the working of the form should/could go there, not the overall program logic.